# How do I reset a variable within an if statement?

Tags: python, list, loops, variables, if-statement

So I am trying to use an if statement that means that if what the user inputs matches a certain pattern then it will print out a message saying 'matches pattern'.
However if it does not match the pattern then I want the inputted variable to then be reseted into another variable because im using it in a list later on.
Baring in mind this is in a loop already so there will be 5 different variables that may or may not fit the pattern that will be going into lists outside of the loop. This is what i have so far, it is in a subroutine outside of the loop for the moment.

```
if phoneNumber=#the pattern#
    print('this fits the pattern')
    else: 
    notphoneNumber=phoneNumber
    return
    #lists: CorrectPhoneNumers=[phoneNumber]
    IncorrectPhoneNumbers=[notphoneNumber]
```

Comment: Can you clarify `I want the inputted variable to then be reseted into another variable...`?

Comment: Please do not post psuedo code. Post your real code.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax aside, are you trying to say something along the lines of
"if the phone number matches the pattern, print "matches pattern" and add the phone number to the list CorrectNumbers, else add the phone number to the list of incorrect numbers"?  Maybe you could try something along the lines of

```
if (phoneNumber matches pattern):
    print "fits pattern"
    CorrectNumbers.append(phoneNumber)
else:
    IncorrectNumbers.append(phoneNumber)
```